# Need a Ruby gem for Cucumber test automation for manipulation of the Excel GUI(ribon,side menus,etc)

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, desktop-application

Am attempting to automate excel , involves manipulation of the Excel GUI(ribbon,side menus,clicking buttons,drop down,etc) to achieve this functionality is one of the more complicated features of the windows desktop application to be automated. Here implementing with Ruby/Cucumber test automation framework.Does anyone know of any ruby gem (or combination of gems) that integrates well with windows desktop applications?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use "roo" gem to handle excelsheet. refer link :-
https://github.com/roo-rb/roo

Thanks,
Kapil Chothe

Comment: Yes I can use "roo" gem for excelsheet not for excel interactive (GUI) operations like switch to ribbon ,click on button etc.